# How to access images from WAMP via PHP in website?

Tags: php, database, web, wampserver

[image]I am developing an application in which i have to place data including images in Wamp server.
I have added these images in Wamp and used their path. Now i want to access those images through  my website using PHP. I am not able to get those images. Code i am using is as follows:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['appimage']) . '" />';
}
```

How can i get and display images saved in database in my website ???/

Comment: ,have you stored images in database or folder..Usually images are stored in folder and only the path is stored in database

Comment: Please clarify: Where are the actual .png files stored and What is in $row[appimage']

Comment: I have stored images in folder and have stored their paths in database. images include .png .jpeg .gif

Answer (score 0):

If the images are on disk then you need something like this:-

Assuming your images are in a directory called `image` under your documentroot then try this, its actually very simple and the `appimage` column holds just the file name like 'pic1.png` for example.

```
echo '<img src="image/' . $row['appimage'] . '"  alt="something descriptive"/>';
```

You do not need to base64 encode anything

Comment: thankyou for help, please see my above picture. now image display like this.